# Koin sharedViewModel with SavedStateHandle

Tags: android, androidx, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm, koin

I have single activity application and number of fragments. Some of these fragments are using my viewmodel, typically like this:

```
private val myViewModel: MyViewModel by sharedViewModel()
```

What if I want to have the model both `shared` and keep its state with SavedStateHandle? I cannot figure out if this is supported and if so, how it needs to be used (declaring viewmodel as stateViewModel in hosting activity is not working).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Update: as koin 2.1.6 is around, they introduced `org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.ext.android.stateSharedViewModel` that you can use in your fragments.

---

Ok after an hour of digging Koin samples and figuring out a few gotchas:

1. Assuming your view model is something similar to this:

```
class SavedStateViewModel(val handle: SavedStateHandle, val service: SimpleService)
```

2. ...and your DI looks like this:

```
viewModel { (handle: SavedStateHandle) -> SavedStateViewModel(handle, get()) }
```

3. Your shared state view model can be consumed in your fragments like this:

```
val sharedSaved: SavedStateViewModel by sharedViewModel()
```

4. (important!) You need this declaration in your activity:

```
lateinit var savedVm: SavedStateViewModel
```

5. (important) You need to call this right after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` in your activity:

```
savedVm  = getStateViewModel()
```

It is important not to use lazy version for the above (stateViewModel).

Comment: have you worked koin multi module in android app project

Comment: nope. for clean architecture stuff? yes, but it's no fit (too complicated, few benefits) for most of the real life projects. overhyped!

Comment: Wouldn't you also have to inject the saved state handle in the activity? How can the activity create a `SavedStateViewModel` without passing the handle as a parameter